# HTML / CSS layout broken using jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a big problem with the layout of a webpage designed for iPad and normal PC displays.
I want to have this layout:

http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/9978/layoutw.png

I already have this layout designed with HTML / CSS and it works in every common webbrowser (Firefox, Safari, Chrome - IEx is not relevant for me):
http://ud05_188.ud05.udmedia.de/spotlight/webpage.html

But now I integrate some jQuery mobile stuff and the layout is broken.
You can see here the website: http://ud05_188.ud05.udmedia.de/spotlight/jquery.html
They div areas are overlapping and it seems that the jquerymobile JavaScript file is the problem.

So how can I identify where the problem is located? What's going wrong here?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Best Regards Tim

Comment: I solved it: http://ud05_188.ud05.udmedia.de/spotlight/jquery.html There were some margins/paddings I have to remove from the jquery mobile css.

Comment: It's better to override them in you own CSS with `!important` so that you can get new jqm css when the release is out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't yet look into multi-box layouts with JQM, but what I can already suggest is:

1. See if it can be done with JQM settings. JQM might have special attributes for your controls. Or you might need extra wrapping divs.
2. Add margins/paddings to your CSS. Adding rounded corners often produces extra width for elements.

And if you manage to figure it out, please post it here as an answer to your own question.